# Ruby Iterating over an array and find match in an hash and replace the element in array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, iteration

I would like someone to clarify how can I possibly iterating over an array, find an exact match in an hash[value], and replace the element in the array with the hash[key].

As example, if I have a morse directory `morse_dict = {
    "a" => ".-","b" => "-...","c" => "-.-.","d" => "-..","e" => ".","f" => "..-.","g" => "--.","h" => "....","i" => "..","j" => ".---","k" => "-.-","l" => ".-..","m" => "--","n" => "-.","o" => "---","p" => ".--.","q" => "--.-","r" => ".-.","s" => "...","t" => "-","u" => "..-","v" => "...-","w" => ".--","x" => "-..-","y" => "-.--","z" => "--.."," " => " ","1" => ".----","2" => "..---","3" => "...--","4" => "....-","5" => ".....","6" => "-....","7" => "--...","8" => "---..","9" => "----.","0" => "-----"
}`

and I want a method that for a given string in morse code returns a string in regular alphabet.
[This is the codewars kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/decode-the-morse-code/train/ruby).

I am not interested in the solution to the challenge itself, I would like to understand the principle of this.

So far I have thought of proceeding this way:

```
def morse_code(arr)
  arr.split(" ").each {|element| 
  element.each_char {|char| 
(morse_dict.include?(char)) ? (print "true") : (print "false")}
  }
end
```

I only print false, which means that I am not actually looking for match into the hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from the kata that letters are to be separated by one space and words by three spaces.

As a first step I will two changes to the hash `morse_dict`: remove the key `' '`; and add key-value pairs for some punctuation characters. The space character key is not needed; the need for punctuation codes is discussed in the kata.

```
PUNCTUATION = { "."=>".-.-.-", ","=>"--..--", "?"=>"..--..", "!"=>"-.-.--" }

ALPHA_TO_MORSE = dict.reject { |k,_| k == " " }.merge(PUNCTUATION)
  #=> {"a"=>".-", "b"=>"-...", "c"=>"-.-.", "d"=>"-..", "e"=>".", "f"=>"..-.",
  #    "g"=>"--.", "h"=>"....", "i"=>"..", "j"=>".---", "k"=>"-.-", "l"=>".-..", 
  #    "m"=>"--", "n"=>"-.", "o"=>"---", "p"=>".--.", "q"=>"--.-", "r"=>".-.",
  #    "s"=>"...", "t"=>"-", "u"=>"..-", "v"=>"...-", "w"=>".--", "x"=>"-..-",
  #    "y"=>"-.--", "z"=>"--..", "1"=>".----", "2"=>"..---", "3"=>"...--",
  #    "4"=>"....-", "5"=>".....", "6"=>"-....", "7"=>"--...", "8"=>"---..",
  #    "9"=>"----.", "0"=>"-----", "."=>".-.-.-", ","=>"--..--", "?"=>"..--..",
  #    "!"=>"-.-.--"}
```

I obtained the Morse codes for the punctuation characters from the [Morse Code Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code#Letters,_numbers,_punctuation,_prosigns_for_Morse_code_and_non-English_variants). Additional punctuation characters could be added if desired.

The hash `ALPHA_TO_MORSE` is used in encoding text. The inverse of this hash is needed for decoding messages in Morse code. Also needed for decoding is the key value pair `"...---..."=>"sos"`.

```
MORSE_TO_ALPHA = ALPHA_TO_MORSE.invert.merge("...---..."=>"sos")
  #=> {".-"=>"a", "-..."=>"b", "-.-."=>"c", "-.."=>"d", "."=>"e", "..-."=>"f",
  #    "--."=>"g", "...."=>"h", ".."=>"i", ".---"=>"j", "-.-"=>"k", ".-.."=>"l",
  #    "--"=>"m", "-."=>"n", "---"=>"o", ".--."=>"p", "--.-"=>"q", ".-."=>"r",
  #    "..."=>"s", "-"=>"t", "..-"=>"u", "...-"=>"v", ".--"=>"w", "-..-"=>"x",
  #    "-.--"=>"y", "--.."=>"z", ".----"=>"1", "..---"=>"2", "...--"=>"3",
  #    "....-"=>"4", "....."=>"5", "-...."=>"6", "--..."=>"7", "---.."=>"8",
  #    "----."=>"9", "-----"=>"0", ".-.-.-"=>".", "--..--"=>",",
  #    "..--.."=>"?", "-.-.--"=>"!""...---..."=>"sos"}
```

One more hash is needed to deal with cases where the message `"sos"` (or `"SOS"`--Morse code is case insensitive), or `"sos"` followed by a punctuation character (e.g., `"sos!"`) is to be encoded.<sup>1</sup> See the Wiki.

```
SOS_WITH_PUNCTUATION = PUNCTUATION.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h["sos#{k}"] = "...---... #{v}" }.merge('sos'=>"...---...")
  #=> {"sos."=>"...---... .-.-.-", "sos,"=>"...---... --..--",
  #    "sos?"=>"...---... ..--..", "sos!"=>"...---... -.-.--", "sos"=>"...---..."}
```

The encoding and decoding methods follow. `encode` checks to see if each word in the string is a key in the hash `SOS_WITH_PUNCTUATION`. If it is, the value of key is the Morse code for the word; else, the word is divided into letters and each letter is translated into Morse code.

```
def encode(str)
  str.strip.downcase.split.map do |word|
    if SOS_WITH_PUNCTUATION.key?(word)
      SOS_WITH_PUNCTUATION[word]
    else
      word.each_char.map { |c| ALPHA_TO_MORSE[c] }.join(' ')
    end
  end.join ('   ')
end

def decode(morse)
  morse.strip.split(/ {3}/).map do |word|
    word.split.map { |c| MORSE_TO_ALPHA[c] }.join
  end.join(' ')
end
```

We can now try out these two methods.

```
str = "  Is now the time for   you, and 007, to send an SOS?"
```

```
morse = encode str
  #=> ".. ...  -. --- .--  - .... .  - .. -- .  ..-. --- .-.  -.-- --- ..- --..--  .- -. -..  ----- ----- --... --..--  - ---  ... . -. -..  .- -.  ...---... ..--.."
```

```
decode morse
  #=> "is now the time for you, and 007, to send an sos?"
```

<sup>1 It would be simpler to have a pre-processing step that would convert, say, `"sos."` to `"sos ."`, but when the resulting Morse code were decoded there would be a space between `"sos"` and `"."`. I suppose that cryptographers could deal with that, but I've chosen to avoid the insertion of the space.</sup>

Comment: Manipulate the string directly works, however I receive this error `rb:60:in block in describe: Expected: "SOS", instead got: nil (Test::Error)` I have added SOS to the dictionary and paired with '...---..." but it still returns `nil`

Comment: What is not clear in "dividing into an array" is: you `.split` your string `morse` into an array of single morse `word`, then iterate over the single `word`, then I don't understand exactly the next iteration when you `.join` the value of MORSE_TO_ALPHA.

Comment: Floors, I apologize for not replying to your comments earlier. I somehow missed them. It’s late now so I’ll look into the problems you mention tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you Cary, I have actually managed to get past the issue by inserting the "SOS" in the dictionary manually and added an if statement just to ensure I could pass the test, and incurred in another error using the different versions of your code as it does not encode back the punctuation (".,!?").

Answer (score 2):

Using [Hash#key](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-key) without replacing the array, rather creating a new one (use `map!` for replacement):

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]    
hash = {a: 4, b: 7, c: 3}

array.map { |el| hash.key(el) }
# => [nil, nil, :c, :a, nil]
```

You may want to think about using [Hash#invert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Hash.html#method-i-invert) and simply referencing the elements by keys for performance reasons as `Hash#key` is `O(n)` while `Hash#[]` is `O(1)`.

```
array = [1,2,3,4,5]
hash = {a: 4, b: 7, c: 3}
inverted_hash = hash.invert

array.map { |el| inverted_hash[el] }
# => [nil, nil, :c, :a, nil]
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming: `arr = 'a b c d'`, which is not an arr, so please make that morse_string

```
def morse_code(morse_string)
  new_elements = []

  # iterate over each character in the string, 
  morse_string.split(" ").each do |element| 
    if morse_dict[element]
      # https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/push
      new_elements.push( morse_dict[element] )
    else
      # whatever you want to do when there is no match
    end
  end
  # re-create the string again, but with braille 
  # https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/join
  new_elements.join(' ')
end

morse_string = 'a b c d'
morse_code(morse_string)
```